# document.querySelector vs. cy.get

Tags: cypress, microsoft-dynamics

i just started using cypress to test a web client from Microsoft Dynamics NAV Business Central. It has dynamic id's with a very complex div structure.

My best guess on how to identify a specific input control is to use aria-label to filter it.

When I do
`document.querySelector('[aria-label^="MyLabel"]')`

I get the element in return. When I try
`cy.get('[aria-label^="MyLabel"]')`

nothing can be found. Am I expecting too much? I also tried

`cy.get('input[type=text]')`

and it returned nothing, although there are several text input fields on the page.

Thanks for your input/help

Update: This is the element I'm trying to find, but due to Dynamics preventing it, I can't copy the whole HTML code

````
<input class="cursorinherit stringcontrol-edit thm-cont-u1-font-size thm-cont-u1-font-stack thm-cont-u1-color-2--maxflat thm-cont-s1-bdrcolor--focus thm-cont-s1-outlinecolor--focus thm-cont-h1-bdrcolor--hover thm-cont-h1-bdrcolor--prev-sib-hover" type="text" spellcheck="false" maxlength="30" aria-label="Paketverfolgungsnr., (Leer)" id="C4ee" title="" autocomplete="autocomplete-off">```
````

Comment: Can you share the HTML DOM for this element ?

Comment: Unfortunately the page doesn't allow me to copy the whole HTML DOM. I've added the element I'm trying to the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the HTML DOM div by div (it felt like there were houndred at least) I realized in the middle of there Microsoft Dynamics included an iframe. This caused my requests within cypress to fail while Chrome console somehow managed to find the items regardless of the iframe.

I looked up some code to use the document of an iframe and was able to find the input element afterwards. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The two ways of getting the elements have different usages

**document.querySelector()**

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector('[aria-label^="MyLabel"]')
console.log(inputEl)
expect(inputEl).to...
```

This is a synchronous call that returns a single element into the variable, which you can then use directly.

**cy.get()**

This is an asynchronous Cypress command that returns one or more elements which must be used inside a `then()` callback,

```js
cy.get('[aria-label^="MyLabel"]').then($inputEl => {
  const inputEl = $inputEl[0]
  console.log(inputEl)
  expect(inputEl).to...
})
```

This looks a lot clunkier, but is necessary when elements themselves are asynchronous (e.g populated by an API call) because the Cypress command repeats until the element arrives on the page.

In contrast `document.querySelector('[aria-label^="MyLabel"]')` will fail if the element is not present at the exact moment the query is run.

**Multiple elements**

Also note the command can get several elements at once, so you can process then together or separately

```js
cy.get('input[type=text]').then($inputEls => {
  const inputEls = [...$inputEls]
  console.log(inputEls)                  // show all
  expect(inputEls).to...
})
```

or

```js
cy.get('input[type=text]').each($inputEl => {
  const inputEl = $inputEl[0]
  console.log(inputEl)                   // show individually
  expect(inputEl).to...
})
```